# storing 13 random values without duplicates from a string array in java

Tags: java, android, random, unique, shuffle

I want distribute 13 values to a string without duplication. i have used random function and shuffle as well but it is giving me 1 value from this String array

```
String[] orgCards = {
                "ca", "ck", "cq", "cj", "c10", "c9", "c8", "c7", "c6", "c5", "c4", "c3", "c2",
                "sa", "sk", "sq", "sj", "s10", "s9", "s8", "s7", "s6", "s5", "s4", "s3", "s2",
                "da", "dk", "dq", "dj", "d10", "d9", "d8", "d7", "d6", "d5", "d4", "d3", "d2",
                "ha", "hk", "hq", "hj", "h10", "h9", "h8", "h7", "h6", "h5", "h4", "h3", "h2"
                };


TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textField);
String listString = "";
for (String i : orgCards) {
    list.add(i);
}
for (int j = 1; j <= 52; j++) {
    Collections.shuffle(list);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        orgCards[i] = list.get(i);
    }

    for (String ss : orgCards) {
        listString = ss;
    }

}
text.setText("my string"+" " + listString);
```

> ```
> output is :
>
> ca
> ```

Comment: Use HashSet this may help you

Comment: @Nilesh if you have used in string array please let me know.

Comment: so you want a string containing 13 random elements from given array?

Comment: yes @Lamorak i want a string containing 13 random elements from given array

Comment: @Kay let me try it .. :)

Comment: @Kay HashSet<String> wordSet = new HashSet<String>(); 
        for(int i=1;i<=13;i++){
            wordSet.add(orgCards[i]);
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will print random 13 strings from the array

```
String[] orgCards = {
        "ca", "ck", "cq", "cj", "c10", "c9", "c8", "c7", "c6", "c5", "c4", "c3", "c2",
        "sa", "sk", "sq", "sj", "s10", "s9", "s8", "s7", "s6", "s5", "s4", "s3", "s2",
        "da", "dk", "dq", "dj", "d10", "d9", "d8", "d7", "d6", "d5", "d4", "d3", "d2",
        "ha", "hk", "hq", "hj", "h10", "h9", "h8", "h7", "h6", "h5", "h4", "h3", "h2"
};

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(orgCards.length);
for (String i : orgCards) {
    list.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(list);
String listString = "";
for (int i=0; i<13; i++) {
    listString += " " + list.get(i);
}

TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textField);
text.setText("my string:" + listString);
```

Comment: thank you man .. working absolutely fine.Now if i want to print random 13 strings from the array among 4 players what should i do ?

Comment: After `Collections.shuffle(list);` the list represents shuffled deck of cards. for player 1 you can take first 13 cards `for (int i=0; i<13; i++)`, then for player 2 `for (int i=13; i<26; i++)` and so on. Other details really depend on what you are trying to build..

Comment: You're welcome! I guess you could also have a use for `List<String> player1 = list.subList(13, 26);`

Comment: i have done it.its not working ..
**
Collections.shuffle(list);
        for (int i=0; i<13; i++) {
            player1 += list.get(i)+" ";

            for (int j=13; j<26; j++){

                player2 += list.get(i)+" ";
            }
            for (int j=26; j<39; j++){

                player3 += list.get(i)+" ";
            }
            for (int j=39; j<52; j++){

                player4 += list.get(i)+" ";
            }

        }**

Comment: where i should i use this piece of code ?

List<String> player1 = list.subList(13, 26);

Comment: wherever you want to if you find it useful

Answer (score 1):

Try change:

```
for (String ss : orgCards) {
    listString = ss; //HERE
}
```

To:

```
for (String ss : orgCards) {
    listString += ss + " ";  
}
```

Comment: yeah! i made a mistake i should use  listString += ss + " ";

Thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (String ss : orgCards) {
    sb.append(ss);
}
```

Use `sb.toString()` for the output.

Comment: i want to store random values but you are just appending it

Comment: I changed your "All- In", so I hope it is more clear, what you mean.

Comment: i want to take 13 strings from this string array and values should be unique

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) to solve this problem.

Example:

```
class Test {  
    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        HashSet<String> al = new HashSet<String>();  
        al.add("Ravi");  
        al.add("Vijay");  
        al.add("Ravi");  
        al.add("Ajay");  

        Iterator<String> itr = al.iterator();  
        while (itr.hasNext()) {  
            System.out.println(itr.next());  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Output:

> Ajay
>   Vijay
>   Ravi